# Qt automatically generated .rc file cannot open include file 'windows.h'

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker, include

In my Qt 5.9.1 project, I wanted to add version info to the executable to help with debugging. So, I added `VERSION = 1.0.0` to the 'Project.pro' file, which automatically generated a 'Project_resource.rc' file, as expected from [Qt Version](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#version).

However, the project now fails to compile, giving the error `RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'` on the line `#include <windows.h>` in 'Project_resource.rc'. I know that `windows.h` is known by the compiler at another point in the program, because in `main.cpp` I `#include <windows.h>` and use a function from there, and that successfully compiles. I just can't figure out why the 'Project_resource.rc' can't find that same file.

Note: I have the following above the `VERSION = 1.0.0` line in 'Project.pro', which is how my `main.cpp` can find `<windows.h>`.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/ucrt"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.10240.0/ucrt/x64"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/um"
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.10240.0/um/x64"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.10240.0/shared"
```

Comment: Why not use [**QVersionNumber**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qversionnumber.html) for version.

Comment: @ErrorSyntacticRemorse: QVersionNumber has nothing to do with what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @ErrorSyntacticRemorse I'm specifically looking to embed version data within the executable file itself (so I can know it without needing to run the exe). QVersionNumber doesn't provide that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Remember .rc files have their own AdditionalIncludeDirectories.

It's possible that your project had set the Windows SDK properly set as one of the Include Directories values (hence your .cpp file resolves the windows.h header file) but not the .rc file (which would explain why windows.h can't be resolved from it).

If you're using Visual Studio 2019, try this:

1. Right click your .rc file on the Solution Explorer
2. Go to Resources -> General
3. Edit the Additional Include Directories
4. Include $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) Macro
5. Be sure to accept and save the change.

You should stop seeing this error right after having done this.
If the ".rc file cannot open include file" was referring to a different file, just try the same but use the proper macro/path value on step 4.